# apt-get upgrade fails on mysql 5.7.40-0ubuntu0.16.04.1+esm1-log

Tags: apt, dpkg, mysql, esm

On Ubuntu 16.04 ESM, upgrades went fine for a while. When it initially upgraded MySQL to 5.7.40, it ran the post-install script successfuly - so all the tables are in good shape and everything works, but now each time I run update followed by upgrade, it tries to "complete" the mysql install - I'm not sure where it is failing, but when it does fail, it has stopped mysql and hasn't re-started it. Using systemctl start mysql gets it running again and reboots work, but I can't figure out how to mark it as "configured". If anyone knows how to force it to a configured state I'd apppreciate it.

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.40-0ubuntu0.16.04.1+esm1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst: line 143: /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

BTW - I've tried creating /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks and making it executable, but it still fails...
Also - I keep the data in /u/mysql/data vs. /var/lib/mysql and it hasn't bitten me before, so I'm stumped!
TIA

Comment: This question is specific to a release of Ubuntu which has reached its end of standard support date, and is not related to asking for help to upgrade to a supported release. Such questions are considered unsupported and off-topic on Ask Ubuntu. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of it's supported status, here's the answer: Edit /var/lib/dpkg/status and find -both- entries for mysql-server - one will show as 'unpacked' and one will show as 'half-configured'. Change both of them to 'installed'. And remove the Config-Version lines...